# Convert value in all rows to VARBINARY(50)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to upgrade all columns in a table, what I am aiming to do is retreive a column from the row it will update then update it, something like:

```
update works 
set encrpyted_item_no = (CAST(RTrim((
    select unencrypted_item_no 
    from works 
    where name = name
) AS VARBINARY(50))
```

I know that query is wrong, it's just an example to show you what I am aiming to do.

I want it to select the column `unencrypted_item_no` from its row then update that same row with the data it gets from `unencrypted_item_no`, **doing this for the whole table**.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: So if you have two rows with the same name, and one of them has item_no = 5 and the other has item_no = 3, which one wins?

Comment: If it's from the same exact row, then you should not use a subquery, as Bort and Gaby suggested. If it's data from the same table but not necessarily that same row then you'd do an additional FROM.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to do a sub-select, referencing the other column in the set will work on a row by row basis, ie:

```
UPDATE works 
SET encrpyted_item_no = CAST(RTrim(unencrypted_item_no) AS varbinary(50))
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be enough ?

```
update works 
set encrypted_item_no = CAST(RTrim(unencrypted_item_no) AS VARBINARY(50))
```